# C# LINQ find where name is in list

Tags: c#, linq, collections

i have a List of objects and i want to sort by a certain field and then find out what "rank" or index is a certain name.

for example, lets say i have a:

```
List<Location> Locations= new List<Location>();
```

and i want to sort by Popularity

```
var list = this.Locations.OrderBy(r => r.PopularityPct);
```

i now want to find out what is the index of "Spain" (**NOTE**:  "Spain" would be a lookup of the **Name** property, where **Name** would be a property of the location object) now that this list is sorted by popularity.

what is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily get *all* of the names and indexes like this:

```
var list = this.Locations.OrderBy(r => r.PopularityPct)
                         .Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
```

Then, for example:

```
var spainIndex = list.Single(x => x.value.Name == "Spain").index;
```

Or print everything:

```
foreach (var pair in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.index, pair.value.Name);
}
```

This is assuming you want the *post-sorted* rank. If you want the index in the *initial* list, you'd switch the order:

```
var list = this.Locations.Select((value, index) => new { value, index });
                         .OrderBy(r => r.value.PopularityPct);
```

Comment: i am getting a compile error on the `var spainindex`line saying "Cannot apply operater == to operands of type "string" with "Location""

Answer (score 0):

First sort locations, then...

```
from index in Enumerable.Range(0, Locations.Count)
let r = Locations[index]
..WHERE CLAUSE
select index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
public static int FindIndexOf(IEnumerable<Location> items,string val)
{
    int index = -1;
    items.Where((x, i) => {
                var ret = x.City == val;
                if (ret)
                    index = i;
                return ret;
            }).ToList();
    return index;
}
```

I know this is weird :)